# Apache2 - how to close port 80 entirely and force the browser to automatically use HTTPS?

Tags: apache, ssl, phpmyadmin

I'm running the newest Debian Wheezy and I'm configuring an Apache2 server with phpMyAdmin running, not more. I have installed a self-signed certificate by:

  * Removing
  **default**
  file in
  **/etc/apache2/sites-available**

  * Modifying
  **default-ssl**
  file to add paths for certificate and certificate key

  * Renaming
  **default-ssl**
  to
  **default**

  * service apache2 restart

Certificate is indeed working but not quite as I have expected.
 
**My goal is to shut down port 80 for Apache entirely and to make the browser use HTTPS automatically for any sites, including phpMyAdmin.** The first problem is that I have to manually add *https://* in URL to be able to open a default site from */var/www* - I expected it to redirect automatically to HTTPS. The second one is phpMyAdmin not working really well with SSL. When I open `http://10.0.0.8/phpmyadmin` in my browser, site opens without SSL certificate and after I try to log in, it redirects me to `http://10.0.0.8/phpmyadmin/index.php` which results in the browser showing "Connection Refused". After opening the site with *https://* instead, everything is working perfectly.
What have I done for now is I commented two first lines in **ports.conf** to turn off listening in port 80. Also I tried to force phpMyAdmin to use SSL by adding `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` in **config.inc.php** and making a .htaccess file to redirect the user to SSL site with `Redirect permanent /phpmyadmin https://10.0.0.8/phpmyadmin`
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I added the following line into the default apache2 conf file for the default port 80 server. This is the conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
Redirect permanent /phpMyAdmin https://your-full-domain-name-or-ip/phpMyAdmin
```

Remember to restart your apache2 server with

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Anyone trying to visit your phpMyAdmin would then be redirected to SSL.